# Probability of Intersection between $B$ and NOT $A$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There are two events, $P(A) = .45$ & $P(B) = .65$. Also, $P( A \cap B) = .25$.

How can I get $P (B \cap A^c)$ ?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Draw a Venn diagram, with an oval representing $B$. Draw an oval representing $A$, and meeting the oval for $B$.  The event $A\cap B$ is then in your picture. The event $B\cap A'$ is the rest of $B$, probability $0.65-0.25$. The information we are given about the probability of $A$ is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice, $$P(B\cap A^{c})=P(B)-P(B\cap A)$$
Since, $P(B\cap A)=P(A\cap B)$, hence
$$P(B\cap A^{c})=P(B)-P(A\cap B)$$
Setting the corresponding values $P(B)=0.65$  & $P(A\cap B)=0.25$
$$P(B\cap A^{c})=0.65-0.25=\color{red}{0.40}$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
$$P(B)=P (B \cap A^c)+P (B \cap A)$$